# VB and Oracle connectivity

Tags: oracle, vb6

What are the steps to connect to Oracle 9i with VB6?  How can I use modules and stored procedures in VB6 and how can I call an SP?

What is the method to use ADO which is helpful to insert, update, search and delete the items from the front end?

Comment: Reads like a homework question to me.

Comment: lol "plzsendtehcodez" sounds like a Gortok invention.

Answer (score 4):

You will need ADO to connect to Oracle (add reference to microsoft activex data objects library).

You need to know where is the Oracle Instance hosted alongwith username and password?

The connection string for Oracle can be found from www.connectionstrings.com

ADODB.Connection is the one that you will need to establish the connection.
Connection has Execute method - which you can use for any insert/update/delete statements.

Now, read some documentation on ADO object library from MSDN.
And, write the code by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose between the Oracle OLEDB driver (which I think comes with the Oracle client install mentioned by YogoZuno) or one from Microsoft (can't remember if it was just a standard microsoft oledb driver or one released with a nod towards oracle): in any case, the Oracle OLEDB driver is far better.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to have the Oracle client installed on your PC, along with an appropriate TNS Names file. Also, be aware that there are some minor functional differences between various versions of the Oracle 9 client - I had some issues under v9.2.0.1, that did not occur under v9.2.0.7.